# A random variable converges to a normal, does the ratio of the probabilities of two events converge to the ratio of the densities?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have a discrete random variable $W_{n}$ that converges in distribution to a normal $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. For two points $a,b$ of the domain, is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{P(W_{n}=a)}{P(W_{n}=b)}=\frac{f_{X}(a)}{f_{X}(b)}$ where $f_{X}$ is the density function of the normal distribution? How can I prove it?

I have $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(W_{n}=a)=\lim_{n \to \infty} P(W_{n}=b)=0$, so how can I solve the indeterminate form?

Comment: This question is a bit weird to me, because under "realistic" circumstances, the support of the $W_n$ will be quite different as $n$ grows. Think about for example the shifted/rescaled binomial distribution, say with $p=1/2$. Then what is converging is $\frac{X-n/2}{\sqrt{n/4}}=\frac{2X}{\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n}$, which ranges from $-\sqrt{n}$ to $\sqrt{n}$. Its CDF has jumps at $\frac{2k-n}{\sqrt{n}}$ for $k=0,1,\dots,n$...which means that that ratio will be quite badly behaved, since this distribution only takes on integer multiples of $1/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Thus for instance if $a$ and $b$ are two integers then there is no hope of this making any sense at all, because for prime $n$ the distribution never takes on an integer value.

Comment: Thanks! I posted the full problem I have below the answer I got... maybe it makes more sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't conclude this for $a \ne b$. Note that weak convergence to a Gaussian random variable is equivalent to pointwise convergence of the CDF. Since $P(W_n = a)$ is the size of the jump of the CDF at $a$, you just need to choose the CDF in a way that lets the jumps at $a$ and $b$ converge to zero with different speeds.

Comment: Thanks! Then I try to post the full problem I have. Let ($X_{a,n}, X_{b,n}, X_{c,n}$) be distributed as a Multinomial($a,b,1-a-b$) where the probabilities of successes $a,b$ are both positive. I am interested in the random variable $W_n=X_{b,n}-X_{a,n}$ that gives the difference in the number of successes for the first two categories. I should have $E[W]=n(b-a)$ and $Var[W]=n(a(1-a)+b(1-b)+2ab)$ and also that $\frac{Wn-E[W]}{Sqrt(Var[W])}$ converges in distribution to N(0,1). What does $\frac{P(W=0)}{P(W=1)}$ converge to?

Comment: i.e. what does the ratio of the probability of having the same number of successes for the first two categories over the probability of having one success more for the second category converge to?